# Express.js checar se requisição é feita por iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, express.js, cross-domain

Como checar se requisição é feita por `iframe` em **"express.js"**?

Exemplo:

**site A:**

```
<iframe src="http://siteb.com/router">
```

**site B:**

```
app.get('/router', (req, res, next) =>
    // logica...
})
```

A questão não é a origem más simplesmente verificar se esta sendo carregado a partir de um `iframe`.

Comment: Eu acho que isso vai ser dificil de conseguir direto pelo express por ele ser back-end Lauro, tem como saber se a página está dentro de um *iFrame* diretamente no front-end.

Comment: No front-end estou usando `window.top !== window.self` para verificar... funciona más não é o que procuro :(

Comment: Você consegue aplicar uma lógica pra saber quando é válido ou não? Pode verificar a url de origem, se ela for diferente da do seu conhecimento generalizar como frame..